# Formula for 3D solid shape z[x][y]

Tags: python, geometry

There is a x-y plane and a height z. The four points of the x-y coordinates and their heights are known.

```
z[10][10] = 10 # x = 10, y = 10
z[100][10] = 20 # x = 100, y = 10
z[10][100] = 20 # x = 10, y = 100
z[100][100] = 60 # x = 100, y = 100
```

Can we derive the formula for z with relation with x and y?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math    
x = 10, 100, 10, 100
y = 10, 10, 100, 100
z = 10, 20, 20, 60

if x > y:
    z = y * math.floor(x/50)
if y > x:
    z = x * math.floor(y/50)
```

This is the closest I can get.
The x = 100 and y = 100 means z = 60 doesn't make sense:
I need more examples...

You are basically saying:
*f*(z) = {something} *y* {some operation} {something} *x*

To restate, you are asking to figure out a 3 variable system based on 1 equation per system. The changes from x and y to z are *inconstant*.

Comment: With only these, it's not a possible solution

Comment: There is no possible plugin to make this true for all give x, y, and z's

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x;
int y;
double z[10][10];

int main()
{
    z[0][0] = 10;
    z[9][0] = 20;
    z[0][9] = 20;
    z[9][9] = 60;
    for (y=0; y<10; y++)
    {
        z[0][y] = (20-10)/9.0*y+10;
        z[9][y] = (60-20)/9.0*y+20;
    }
    for (y=0; y<10; y++)
    {
        for (x=1; x<10; x++)
        {
            z[x][y] = (z[9][y]-z[0][y])/9.0 + z[x-1][y];
        }
    }
    for (y=0; y<10; y++)
    {
        for (x=0; x<10; x++)
        {
            cout<<(z[x][y])<<"\t";
            if (x==9)
            {
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it produces:

```
10      11.1111 12.2222 13.3333 14.4444 15.5556 16.6667 17.7778 18.8889 20
11.1111 12.5926 14.0741 15.5556 17.037  18.5185 20      21.4815 22.963  24.4444
12.2222 14.0741 15.9259 17.7778 19.6296 21.4815 23.3333 25.1852 27.037  28.8889
13.3333 15.5556 17.7778 20      22.2222 24.4444 26.6667 28.8889 31.1111 33.3333
14.4444 17.037  19.6296 22.2222 24.8148 27.4074 30      32.5926 35.1852 37.7778
15.5556 18.5185 21.4815 24.4444 27.4074 30.3704 33.3333 36.2963 39.2593 42.2222
16.6667 20      23.3333 26.6667 30      33.3333 36.6667 40      43.3333 46.6667
17.7778 21.4815 25.1852 28.8889 32.5926 36.2963 40      43.7037 47.4074 51.1111
18.8889 22.963  27.037  31.1111 35.1852 39.2593 43.3333 47.4074 51.4815 55.5556
20      24.4444 28.8889 33.3333 37.7778 42.2222 46.6667 51.1111 55.5556 60
```

May I know how to make it to python code? Python 2D array format is different from C++.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).